# 404 error in spring MVC - "the requested resource not found" for a simple registration/login program

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am working on a basic registration/login program in spring MVC. Below code shows me 404 error - the requested resource is not found. I have gone through the code multiple times but I didn't find a clue. So how can I solve it? Please help.

login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form:form action="inslogin" method="get" modelAttribute="log">
        <form:hidden path="id"/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>First name:</td>
                <td><form:input path="fname"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>      
                <td>Last name:</td>
                <td><form:input path="lname" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="insert"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>


</body>
</html>
```

logincontroller.java

```
package com.dipen.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.dipen.dao.logindao;
import com.dipen.vo.loginvo;

@Controller
public class logincontroller {
    @Autowired
    logindao logind;
    @Autowired
    loginvo loginv;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView home(){
        return new ModelAndView("login","log",new loginvo());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/inslogin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView insertname(@ModelAttribute loginvo loginv){

        System.out.println("start of insertname method");
        int i = loginv.getId();
        if(i==0){
            logind.insertlogin(loginv);
            System.out.println("if part");

        }
        else{
            logind.updatelogin(loginv);
            System.out.println("else part");

        }
        System.out.println("end of insertname method");
        ModelAndView mv1=new ModelAndView("welcome");//file name
        return  mv1;

    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView search(@ModelAttribute loginvo loginv){
        System.out.println("start of search method");

        List ls = logind.searchdata(loginv);
        System.out.println("done");
        ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView("search");
        mv.addObject("abc",ls);
        System.out.println("sss"+ls.size());
        System.out.println("end of search method");
        return mv;

    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/delete.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView delete(@ModelAttribute loginvo loginv,@RequestParam int id){
        loginv.setId(id);
        logind.delete(loginv);
        ModelAndView mv1=new ModelAndView("redirect:/search");
        return mv1;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/login.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView update(@ModelAttribute loginvo loginv,@RequestParam int id){


        System.out.println("start of update method");

        ModelAndView mv1 = new ModelAndView("login");

        loginvo r = this.logind.getRowById(id);
        System.out.println("update controller : "+r.getFname());
        mv1.addObject("log",this.logind.getRowById(id));
        return mv1;

        /*List ls = new ArrayList();
        loginv.setId(id);
        ls = logind.searchdatabyid(loginv);*/
        /*System.out.println(ls.size());*/  

    }
}
```

logindao.java

```
package com.dipen.dao;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.omg.PortableInterceptor.SYSTEM_EXCEPTION;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.dipen.vo.loginvo;

@Repository
@Transactional
public class logindao {
    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public String insertlogin(loginvo loginv) {
        try {
            Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
            Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(loginv);
            tr.commit();
            session.close();
            System.out.println("dao inserlogin");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getCause());
        }
        return "Record Inserted...";
    }

    public List searchdata(loginvo loginv) {
        List ls = new ArrayList();
        try {
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            Query q = session.createQuery("from loginvo");
            ls = q.list();

            System.out.println("dao searchdata");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ls;
    }
/*  public List searchdatabyid(loginvo loginv) {
        List ls = new ArrayList();
        try {
            Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            Query q = session.createQuery("from loginvo where id='"+loginv.getId()+"'");
            ls = q.list();

            System.out.println("dao searchdatabyid");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ls;
    }
*/
    public loginvo getRowById(int id){
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        loginvo lv = (loginvo)session.load(loginvo.class,id);
        System.out.println("ID :"+lv.getId());
        System.out.println("Fname :"+lv.getFname());
        return lv;
    }




    public void delete(loginvo loginv) {

        try {
            Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            /* Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession(); */
            /* Transaction tr=session.beginTransaction(); */
            Query q = session.createQuery("delete loginvo where id='"+loginv.getId()+ "'");
            q.executeUpdate();
            /* tr.commit(); */
            session.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String updatelogin(loginvo loginv) {
        try {
            System.out.println("inside updatelogin");

            Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
            Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(loginv);
            tr.commit();
            session.close();

            System.out.println("dao updatelogin");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getCause());
        }
        return "Record Updated...";
    }

}
```

loginvo.java

```
package com.dipen.vo;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;    
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class loginvo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="fname")
    private String fname;

    @Column(name="lname")
    private String lname;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }
}
```

welcome.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Did it !!!</h1>

    <form:form action="search" method="get" modelAttribute="searchall">
        <input type="submit" value="search">
    </form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

search.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>


    <table border="1px">
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Firstname</td>
            <td>Lastname</td>
            <td>Update</td>
            <td>Delete</td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${abc}" var="j">
            <tr>
                <td>${j.id}</td>
                <td>${j.fname}</td>
                <td>${j.lname}</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="login.html?id=${j.id}">Update</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="delete.html?id=${j.id}">delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </c:forEach>
    </table>


</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<display-name>Spring_insert</display-name>
<!-- <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list> -->
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<!-- <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>-->

</web-app>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />


    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dipen" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.dipen.vo.loginvo</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="logindao" class="com.dipen.dao.logindao">
    </bean>

    <bean id="loginvo" name="Student" class="com.dipen.vo.loginvo">
    </bean>

</beans>
```

[image: file structure]

Comment: http://localhost:8080/Spring_insert/

Comment: dont know where to find server log :| @MohammadFaisal

Comment: @dipenbaks You need to learn naming conventions. Read more on here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Comment: thanks for the suggestion and I will learn that but right now can you answer me on this question ? :)

Comment: dont know where to find server log :| @MohammadFaisal

Comment: dnt knw where to find server log @hurricane

Comment: If you running in eclipse logs written to console view. It should be at the bottom by default. There you should see exceptions. If you running on tomcat it will be in logs directory, file named catalina.out if you haven't configured logging yet.

Comment: The application itself starts successfully?

Comment: it shows me multiple this : org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
 @MohammadFaisal

Comment: @hurricane org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Comment: no its just getting me an error of 404

Comment: you have to post the full stack trace!

Comment: Try to map @RequestMapping("/") to something like @RequestMapping("/home") and then hit that URL: localhost:8080/Spring_insert/home

Comment: @TimeTravel ..its saying the answer lengh is limited, how am i supposed to post all the console ?

Comment: post the stacktrace in http://pastebin.com and provide a link here

Comment: @TimeTravel the console : http://pastebin.com/3HLgkA2N

Comment: the console : http://pastebin.com/3HLgkA2N  @MohammadFaisal

Answer (score 1):

You have `jsp` files under `WEB-INF` but your `prefix` seems to be incorrect. Change it with

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Comment: @dipenbaks: you have not updated the exception log. please update your question with the log.